# CSS responsive font-size for different viewports calculation explanation

Tags: css, responsive, viewport, font-size, calc

I read this [**article**](https://zellwk.com/blog/viewport-based-typography/). At the end of this article `font-size: calc(0.875em + 0.25 * (100vw - 80em) / 40);` will work in any viewport. We can use this calc method for **responsive font sizes** for different viewports. I agree it works. But, I don't understand from which values they got **0.875em**, **0.25**, **80em** & **40**. Can anyone explain from which numbers they got these values??

```
html {
  font-size: calc(0.875em + 0.25 * (100vw - 80em) / 40);
}
```

Comment: what was not clear in the article? answering your question is almost repeating what was already said there. If you follow the logic from the beginning you will understand everything but if you jump to the end and pick the last formula you won't get it

Comment: @TemaniAfif In this line `calc(0.875em + 0.25 * (100vw - 80em) / 40);` from which numbers how can I get 0.25?

Comment: read the full article, there is a detailled explanation for each number

Answer (score -1):

If you ignore all the units, the result of this mathematical equation is going to be 1.

Now em is a **scalable unit**. For example, if your h1 is 36pt, 1em is going to be  36pt and 2em will be 72pt.

The trick here is the **100vw which is equal to the viewport width** and it works on window resize.

So by doing this, you will scale the font size according to the width of your browser window without the use of media queries.

The reason for the numbers 0.875em, 0.25, 80em & 40 is to make sure you have a valid CSS property and to end up with 1 as a result.

Having `font-size: calc(1.125em * (100vw - 80em) / 40);` is not valid.

Comment: ignore all the units?  how can the units be ignored... all browsers support `em` and most support `vw`... is adding up to be 1 just a coincidence or...  I don't quite get the line "The reason for the numbers 0.875em, 0.25, 80em & 40 is to make sure you have a valid CSS property and to end up with 1 as a result."... have a valid CSS property... (of?)  and end up with a 1... 1 with any unit?

Comment: after taking course ( Advanced CSS and Sass: Flexbox, Grid, Animations and More! ) by Jonas Schmedtmann on udemy I came to know that we should do something like this in order to have responsive font size in all web pages 

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  /* default font size is 10px -> 10/16 = 0.625 * 100% font size of browser*/ 
}

and then you can use anywhere like this 
 .className { font-size : 1rem }

Comment: Let’s say you want your font size to be 18px when viewport is at 600px and 22 when is at 100px. First, you need to convert the smaller value in percentage like this: calc(18/16 *100%);
Then, you need to calculate the vw amount like this font-size (22 -28), divide it by the difference in viewport widths (1000 - 600) and multiply it my 100vw - smaller-viewport-width (100vw - 600px).
So you end up with something like this:
 font-size: calc(112.5% + 4 * (100vw - 600px) / 400)

Comment: @FlorinSimion I understand this calculation `font-size: calc(112.5% + 4 * (100vw - 600px) / 400)`. But, how these values `calc(0.875em + 0.25 * (100vw - 80em) / 40);` are generated??